# Unable to read WSDL from Coldfusion9

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-9

I've the problem now. I've run the following code in CF8 is ok and everything's fine.

```
<cfinvoke webservice="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL" method="CelsiusToFahrenheit" returnvariable="strg">
    <cfinvokeargument name="Celsius" value="24" />
</cfinvoke>

<cfdump var="#strg#">
```

But test it in CF9. Then encounter the following error

Unable to read WSDL from URL: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL. Error: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.w3schools.com.
The error occurred on line 2.

What I need to know is **Is there I need to configure in Coldfusion admin or somewhere else?** I've already tried to add above webservices URL in CFadmin > webservices but cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works fine in CF9 even without registering the webservice in CF admin. Try to restart ColdFusion or reboot the server. Your problem seems to be more DNS related than to be a CF issue. Probably the underlying JVM cached outdated DNS data or your server has problems firing DNS queries. Check firewall settings if restart doesn't help.

Comment: UnknownHostException - try pinging that host and see if that works. It seems like a n/w issue.

Comment: The one thing is CF server has been configured with multiple instances.

Comment: Ah.. sorry.. my bad.. the server installed CF9 cannot access Internet.